# Bazel optional data attribute file

Tags: bazel

I would like to have a file optionally provided to the `data` attribute and have my program to deal with the file being present or not.

If the file doesn't exist, bazel reports `missing input file...`

```
cc_binary(
    name = "test",
    srcs = ["main.c"],
    data = [":conf.yml"]
)
```

Is there any way to make it optional ?

Answer (score 0):

No. Bazel requires all inputs to be declared statically for hermeticity and determinism. The way forward here is to make an empty `conf.yml` and have the program determine if it's empty or not.

Comment: there's one way to hack around it: use `glob(["conf.yml"])`. `glob()` runs during loading before analysis, and so it can safely return nothing if the file isn't there. The include pattern will only match `conf.yml`, so it shouldn't erroneously match other files.

Comment: @ahumesky Works like a charm thanks ! Please make a separate answer if you want me to approve it.